# How to specify the dynamic linker for a shared library used in a java native program

Tags: java, linux, linker, java-native-interface

I tried to integrate some c program into spark environment.

I created a dynamic library (i.e. libA.so) and then load/run it with JNI interface.

Now my problem is:

In the environment where I deploy spark (yarn) the gcc version is quite low, I have to put all necessary system c libs in all yarn nodes. I built the dynamic library with ld option (-WL, -rpath=clib), (all basic c libraries are put in clib folder). It works if I built the c program as executable with linking option (-WL, -dynamic-linker=clib/ld-linux-some-version.so.2) and run it on all yarn node.

But now the program starts with java, java will automatically use the default linker instead of the linker I want (in the clib folder)

“ldd libA.so” shows like that

```
libc.so.6 => clib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdb7de88000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000559241cf3000)
```

Is there a way to specify the linker in java program ? or specify the linker when I built libA.so ?

Thanks very much

Comment: You can try to use LD_PRELOAD and specify version you want

Comment: @mko thanks mko, I haven’t used this before. I would try it. It would be great if you could explain it more in details.

Comment: This trick allows you to load library before anything else. I think, this article explains give quite good fell of usage: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7795